# Do I need "there" in "In my room is a bed"?

Tags: grammar, adverbs

I want to know what is wrong with this sentence.

"In my room is a bed."

How should I use "there" and why?

Comment: There is no need for an unusual word order even though it is grammatical. There is a bed in my room.

Comment: 'There' is not necessary at all. I think you need to provide a context for any word you feel should be part of the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that it is grammatical, but not natural, without *there*.

It's grammatical because the fronted locative phrase *In my room* serves to put the verb *is* in second place, where it usually needs to be (*Is a bed in my room* would not be a grammatical sentence for that reason, unless it was a question).

I can't explain why it's not natural without *there*, though.